# Accessing the value of a table and comparing it with a string in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am facing trouble with comparing a value in table 1 against a string
Here is what ive tried..

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS comment_trigger$$
CREATE TRIGGER  comment_trigger AFTER INSERT ON post_comments
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
@var_post_id varchar(20);
BEGIN
IF (NEW.post_id LIKE 'rmdid%') THEN
SET @var_post_id=SELECT post_id FROM recommendations WHERE recommendation_id=NEW.post_id;
IF(@var_post_id LIKE 'recid%') THEN
UPDATE cooking_category SET last_activity=NEW.comment_time WHERE post_id=NEW.post_id;
END IF;
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Can someone help me with this please.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: The value i am obtaining using the select statement should be put into a variable so that i can compare it against a string.I couldn't find a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the variable directly in the `select` statement:

```
SELECT @var_post_id = post_id
FROM recommendations
WHERE recommendation_id=NEW.post_id;
```

This is preferred, but your syntax would also work if you put parentheses around the `select` statement:

```
SET @var_post_id=(SELECT post_id FROM recommendations WHERE recommendation_id=NEW.post_id);
```

Comment: after this can i use something like IF(@var_post_id=="foo")

Comment: I removed the DECLARE statement.Its not showing any error now but it isnt performing the update